# Undoing Higher-Order Derivatives Using Multiple Integrals

Tags: calculus

I am well aware that higher order derivatives are used very frequently, but why is it that, at least in undergraduate math, there is never any time given to "undoing" a higher order derivative?  For example, I've never seen any problem that states: Given $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$, find the value of $f$ by computing $\iint\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\,dxdx$.  One would think that problems that require calculating position from an acceleration function would be common and useful, so how come there never seem to be any?

Comment: If you know how to "undo" a first order derivative, you can iterate this to "undo" derivatives of any higher order. For a beginner, this obviously is a very useful technique and works in many cases (as the one you mentioned).

Comment: True.  I'm just wondering why such problems are never given out as homework in Calc I/II classes.  It's not really important, just something that was on my mind.

By the way, why did you qualify your statement by saying "for a beginner?"

Comment: If you are interested in an educators point of view, you might want to head over to [MathEducators.SE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) and give it a try. Using "for a beginner" should prevent people from coming up with more complicated situations where you can't just integrate the second-order differential of a function two times to gain the original function. If you don't have a reasonably simple version of the fundamental theorem of calculus, I guess it might be very hard if not impossible to apply that technique to concrete examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to your question:

1. [Differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation). You haven't specified your level, so I don't know how much of these you have seen, but solving differential equations is a very, very, very large generalisation of finding antiderivatives. The point is that the dependence is considerably more complicated than just having a derivative and wanting to find the function: you have various orders of derivatives related to each other and to the function itself. (And then of course there's their sinister cousin, the [integral equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation), rarely taught, but occasionally required. (And lastly, the [Integro-differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integro-differential_equation), which I've had some dealings with myself, is the worst of the lot.))
2. There is a simple inverse to the operator $(d/dx)^n$: it's called the [Cauchy formula for repeated integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration):
   $$ D_a^{-n} f(x) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_a^x (x-t)^{n-1} f(t) \, dt, $$
   for any particular $a$ you fancy. Obviously there's also an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n-1$ floating around as well. The generalisations of this to inverses of other differential operators are called [Green's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function). Another sort of generalisation is the [fractional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus), which is most often computed as an integral, because integrals are better-behaved than derivatives (and way cooler, in the opinion of the author).

But obviously all this stuff requires considerably more theory than you cover in your first couple of courses on calculus.

Comment: In case you want to know, I'm currently taking a very theoretical math course that combines multivariable calc (in n dimensions, not the usual two or three), linear algebra, and diffeq in two semesters, but all we've done so far is multivariable calc.  But I've never seen the topics you've mentioned, so thanks for that!

Comment: But I don't take an official advanced calculus course that proves everything until next year.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that such problems are relatively common. Consider: "A ball is thrown upward at time $t=0$ from position $x_0$ at a velocity of $v_0$. What is it's position at time $t$?" The issue is that such problems are relatively boring compared to problems like "A mass $m$ is on spring with spring constant $k$. At $t=0$, a spring is released from rest extended to length $x_0$. What is its position at time $t$? In the latter situation, the acceleration cannot be written directly (at first) as a function of time, so we have to use techniques of solving ODE's to answer the question. The latter problem is more representative of real problems, even when we are talking about second derivatives which are not literally an acceleration.